# How do I see all my database tables in server MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can only see two tables of my database in server MySQL Workbench. I have five tables in my database but when I try to access my tables from server there are only two tables.

My database name is movie and I have actor, genre, movies, reviews, cast tables but when I query from MYsql command line I get these results.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| ep-store           |
| movie              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| test               |
| world              |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> use movie;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_movie |
+-----------------+
| actor           |
| genre           |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: the only tables on database schema movies are actor and genre. Are you sure you created them in correct place - well you shouldn't be sure, because from the info you supplied you haven't. Most likel you createde them under the "wrong" schema.

Comment: Whatever shows in server shows up in Workbench!

Comment: When I display EER diagram of databases I can see other tables but I can see them from server.